# Removing Java completely from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: java

When I run `which java` command in my Ubuntu, it tells `/usr/bin/java`.

I initially installed java using `sudo apt-get install ...` command. Using this command where does it install all java components?

In my system in `/usr/lib/jvm` i see the following listings:

```
java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64  java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

I want to completely remove Java, I tried Googling, but the instructions used in didn't work. Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: Possible, but he was also asking why is `which java` says /usr/bin/java instead of where ever the jvm is installed to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is a link to the current alternative of `/usr/bin/java`, you can reconfigure the default java version(including javac and whatnot) by using `update-java-alternatives`. If you want to reconfigure alternatives for a different debian package you can use `update-alternatives --config {package}` instead.

You probably don't want to remove Java, but maybe you want to remove some of the older versions.

If you do want to remove Java 6 you can run

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6*
```

Or to remove Java, but i don't recommend doing this.

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
```

Comment: `update-java-alternatives` should be used instead, since it ensures ALL Java executables are switched over. You don't want to forget `javac` or `jar` or other lesser-known executables.

Comment: Java is really useful, you probably don't want to get rid of it from a desktop. Some updated have been made.